# Can't mount VHD file in Read-write mode using terminal

Tags: 18.04, bash, permissions, mount, ntfs

I have a VHD file which I am using a bash script to mount, I run this in sudo:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/Desktop/VMfiles
echo "make sure to unmount the VHD before starting up the vm, as theres a risk of corruption if the file is mounted in both OSes."
sleep .5
chmod ugo+rwx disk-1.vhd
sleep .5
vhdimount -X allow_root disk-1.vhd /mnt/vhd/
sleep .5
mount -vt ntfs-3g -o ro,noload,offset=32256 /mnt/vhd/vhdi1 /media/user/your/folder
```

---

The command can only mount the vhd file in read only mode, and if I attempt to switch this command:

---

```
mount -vt ntfs-3g -o ro,noload,offset=32256 /mnt/vhd/vhdi1 /media/user/your/folder
```

to this,

```
mount -vt ntfs-3g -o rw,noload,offset=32256 /mnt/vhd/vhdi1 /media/user/your/folder
```

---

This error message appears:

> ntfs-3g-mount: mount failed: Permission denied
> Failed to sync device /dev/loop0: Input/output error
> Failed to close volume /dev/loop0: Input/output error

---

Whats going on here?
How can I enable read-write mode?
OS: Ubuntu 18.04